# Is there an underlying logic/pattern to VS Code keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on learning more VS Code shortcuts (basically via rote memorization) and I'm wondering is there a pattern that makes shortcuts feel more systematic? e.g. certain types of things use option or command vs control?

I see some patterns. For instance:

- Move line up is `opt + UP`
- Copy line up is `opt + shift + UP`

Comment: How extensive must an answer be to be accepted? There are hundred of shortcuts. Any particular keyboard shortcuts you feel are extra hard to remember?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts are most likely defined by and UX designer, that most likely migrated [common patterns](https://medium.com/@sashika/j-k-or-how-to-choose-keyboard-shortcuts-for-web-applications-a7c3b7b408ee) they are used to and used the rules that [felt natural to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4173881/11869748).

One common pattern is to place shortcuts on letter that their actions are related to (like on copy you use "CTRL+C"). But this fails when you think of pasting, where you use V instead of P. Most likely this was done to keep the copy and past actions close together, since they are often chained.

This is usually the only rule that you can be sure when talking about keyboard shortcuts: it makes things more convenient.

Keyboard shortcuts are very personal and VS Code allows you to change them completely to better suit your needs, so if you are adamant on having certain logic behind your shortcuts, you could change them yourself.

Another alternative would be to grab some existing [keymaps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Keymaps&sortBy=Relevance) from the extension marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that shortcuts in the VS Code are systematic. It's rather categories with sometimes absolutely different mapped keys.

I believe, that [KeyBindings section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) in the VS Code documentation is pretty comprehensive and covers all possible shortcuts which are even not assigned by default. As a result, you can look over and either memorize it or remap as you'd like. Alongside that, you can find [Tips & Tricks section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks) which includes a handful list of useful mappings.

Moreover, that section consists of cheatsheets for [Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf), [macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) and [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf). As ZektorH said, keyboard shortcuts are very personal. For example, if you think that VIM keymaps works for you then [just use it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim). Otherwise, check other [options](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Keymaps&sortBy=Installs)